# Detecting screensize correctly with soft navigation bar

Tags: c#, android, xamarin

I am developing an app in C# using Xamarin.  I use the following code to detect the device screensize:

```
var metrics = Resources.DisplayMetrics;
int widthInDp = metrics.WidthPixels / Resources.DisplayMetrics.Density;
int heightInDp = metrics.HeightPixels / Resources.DisplayMetrics.Density;
```

On a device that has physical navigation buttons, and no soft navigation bar, (Samsung SM-E7000), this method returns expected results:

```
360dp x 640dp in portrait mode
640dp x 360dp in landscape mode
```

However, on a device that does not have physical navigation buttons, but has the soft navigation bar, (Nexus 4), this method returns unexpected (to me) results:

```
384dp x 592dp in portrait mode
598dp x 384dp in landscape mode
```

It seems for the Nexus the results allow 48dp for the soft navigation bar in portrait mode, and 42dp in landscape mode.

I want to use the fullscreen - if the device has a soft navigation bar I want to hide it and use the space.  I can hide the soft navigation bar, but I need to be able to detect either the actual screen size (e.g. 384dp x 640dp for the Nexus 4), or whether the device has a soft navigation bar (and preferably its size), so I can adjust for the extra space available when it is hidden.

I have seen several stackoverflow questions answered for Java with code similar to:

```
public boolean hasNavBar (Resources resources)
{
    int id = resources.getIdentifier("config_showNavigationBar", "bool", "android");
    return id > 0 && resources.getBoolean(id);
}
```

but I can't find the C#/Xamarin equivalent.

Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

C# Version:

```
public bool hasNavBar(Resources resources)
{
    int id = resources.GetIdentifier("config_showNavigationBar", "bool", "android");
    return id > 0 && resources.GetBoolean(id);
}
```

Comment: Thank you - appreciated.